# Applying a function split by factors

Tags: r

I have a data frame of stock data with information back 10 years on 100+ stocks.  I am trying to run the MACD function in quantmod on this data but cannot figure out how to split the calculation by different stocks.  For example a little bit of my data frame looks like this:

```
   data<-structure(list(market = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AD1", "AD2", "AD3"), class = "factor"), 
date = structure(c(15623, 15624, 15625, 15628, 15623, 15624, 
15625, 15628, 15625, 15628), class = "Date"), open = c(101.52, 
101.68, 102.1, 101.99, 100.73, 100.85, 101.57, 101.01, 100.56, 
100.42), high = c(102.07, 102.39, 102.36, 102.07, 101.4, 
101.59, 101.62, 101.35, 100.56, 100.71), low = c(101.26, 
101.56, 101.63, 101.5, 100.59, 100.85, 101.07, 100.97, 100.56, 
100.41), last = c(101.78, 102.08, 101.76, 101.91, 101.08, 
101.37, 101.06, 101.21, 100.41, 100.56)), .Names = c("market", 
"date", "open", "high", "low", "last"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(9:10,.Names = c("9", 
"10"), class = "omit"))
```

How do I pass this data frame into the MACD function while getting it to calculate each market separately.  Thank you for the help.  I am new to R.

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `by` here to group by `market` and apply the function to each group.

```
library(quantmod)
by(data,data$market,function(x)
{
  ## coerece the group to an xts object
  dat.xts <- xts(x[,-c(1:2)],x$date)
  ## EMA ~ MACD with type 'EMA'
  EMA( dat.xts,n=min(nrow(dat.xts),10))

})

data$market: AD1
               [,1]
2012-10-10       NA
2012-10-11       NA
2012-10-12       NA
2012-10-15 101.8225
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data$market: AD2
             [,1]
2012-10-10     NA
2012-10-11     NA
2012-10-12     NA
2012-10-15 101.04
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data$market: AD3
             [,1]
2012-10-12     NA
2012-10-15 100.49
```

Comment: This will return just the EMA not the difference between the 13 and 26 day moving average.

Comment: @Tim `MACD` will call internally `EMA`. I don't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `MACD` function in `quantmod` expects `xts` not `data.frame`.

So what you need to do is first split `data.frame` by `market` and then convert each of resultant `data.frame` into `xts` and then apply `macd` function.

```
LL <- split(data, data$market)

result <- lapply(LL, 
       function(DF) { 
           XTS <- xts(DF[, -2], order.by = as.POSIXct(DF$date, format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT"),tzone='GMT')
           return(MACD(XTS$last))                
       }
      )
```

Comment: any idea why I would be getting "Error in rowSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric" error